# Existence of a approximate unit $U_{n}^{2}$ for a $ C^{*}$-algebra $

Tags: c-star-algebras

if ${U_{n}}$ is an approximate unit for a $C^{*}$-algebra  A. Is  ${U_{n}^{2}}$ is an approximate unit for a $C^{*}$-algebra A? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{U_n\}$ be your approximate unit.

The $U_n$ are positive so that the $U_n^2=U_n^*U_n$ are also positive.

Also by the C*-equation we have 
$$\|U_n^2\|=\|U^*_nU_n\|=\|U_n\|^2\leq 1\Rightarrow \|U_n^2\|\leq 1.$$

You should be able to show/find that for any $a\in A$
$$\|U_naU_n-a\|\rightarrow 0\qquad(*)$$
and any $x\in A$ we have
$$\|U_nx-xU_n\|\rightarrow 0.\qquad(**)$$

Note
$$
\begin{align}\|U_n^2a-a\|&\leq \left\|U_n^2 a-U_naU_n\right\|+\|U_naU_n-a\|
\\&=\left\|U_n(U_na)-(U_na)U_n\right\|+\|U_naU_n-a\|\rightarrow0.
\end{align}.$$

Comment: thanks for your reply and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate units are bounded by $1$, so
\begin{align}
\|U_n^2X-X\|&\leq\|U_n^2X-U_nX\|+\|U_nX-X\|=\|U_n(U_nX-X)\|+\|U_nX-X\|\\
&\leq\|U_nX-X\|+\|U_nX-X\|=2\|U_nX-X\|
\end{align}

Comment: thanks. but for increasing the approximate unit U_{N}^{2}  Does not hold, unless C*-algebra is commutative,true?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wasn't thinking about the monotonicity property.

Comment: thanks for your reply and your time.